# PostgreSQL error using pgAdmin4 to upload csv file

Tags: postgresql

I am brand new to `PostgreSQL`.

I created a test table named `Activity`, with a column structure that looks as follows:

```
id    Color    Dimension    Style    COUNT    SUM    Date
```

I defined the columns as follows:

`id`:  bigint, primary key, not null

`Color`:  character varying 255

`Dimension`:  character varying 255

`Style`:  character varying 255

`COUNT`:  bigint

`SUM`:  double precision

`DATE`:  date

My `csv file` has data that looks as follows:

```
Color   Dimension    Style    COUNT    SUM    Date
Blue    Circle       Large    4        800    6/19/2020
Blue    Circle       Small    5        1500   6/19/2020
Blue    Square       Medium   1        15     6/19/2020
```

In `pgAdmin4`, I go through the following steps:

1. in the tree on the left-side pane, I right-click on the Activity table and select "Import/Export"
2. on the resulting dialogue, I switch the "Export" flag to "Import"
3. browse for the file name and select it
4. select the "csv" format
5. select Header = YES

After clikcing "OK", I see the following error message:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type bigint: "Blue"
CONTEXT:  COPY Trades, line 2, column id: "Blue"
```

The csv file does not contain the `id` column (which is the primary key) because my understanding is that PostgreSQL will automatically insert and increment that number based on the number of records I import.

Does anyone see why I'm getting the error message above?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because your CSV file has one less column(id) then the table. The `COPY` command(which is being used by Import) has no idea that this field has a DEFAULT. In the Import dialog there should be a tab named Columns that allows you to select those columns that are in the CSV.

Comment: Yes, in the `Columns` tab, I removed the `id` field and was able to execute the import successfully.  Thank you @Adrian Klaver.